# Regex handling "|" in Text

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I got the following text:

```
Code = ABCD123 | Points = 30
Code = ABCD333 | Points = 44
```

At the end, I want to removing anything except the Code, output:

```
ABCD123
ABCD333
```

I actually tried it with
`Code = | P.+`

But I don't know how to get "|" removed. Currently, I have just `ÀBCD333 |` left as an example. 
I'm struggling there.

Comment: Make sure to escape `|` to match it as a literal char.

Comment: Have you tried ‘\|’ ? The pipe character means “or” in regex unless you escape it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I think the pipe is not the problem, OP wants to keep only the Code value.

Comment: @Toto The *current* problem is handling the pipe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OP's regex, (as far as I understand what he really want) is supposed to match `Code = ` OR `P.+`.

Comment: @dnz: could you clarify what does your regex is supposed to do?

Comment: @Toto I just want to Code e.g. ABCD123 and anything else removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code only consists of word characters, you may use the following:

```
^Code = (\w+).+$
```

..and replace with:

```
\1
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX49Ks/1)**.

If the code can be anything, you may use something like this instead:

```
^Code = (.+?)[ ]\|.+$
```

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Code = (\w+).+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  Code =    # literally
  (\w+)     # group 1, 1 or more word character
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]